# Is RDIMM / LRDIMM different than SDRAM?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have an ASUS WS C422 SAGE motherboard and tried to install a set of 2 CORSAIR Vengeance RGB PRO 32GB DDR4 3200 (PC4-25600) C16 memory cards into it and am getting an invalid memory configuration error from the motherboard (POST fails).

On looking more carefully at the motherboard documentation it says that it supports up to 32GB "RDIMMs" and 32GB and 64GB "LRDIMMs" whatever that means. On Amazon where I purchased the memory, it says that the type is "DDR4 SDRAM". Does that mean it is different than an "RDIMM" or is "SDRAM" a kind of "RDIMM"?

Comment: DDR4 SDRAM (Double Data Rate 4 Synchronous Dynamic Access Memory) is unbuffered, or unregistered RAM, while your motherboard (as it is a server board) only seems to accept registered (or buffered) memory. RDIMM (Registered Dual In Line Memory Module) is commonly used in servers, to allow for more memory capacity from each controller. LRDIMM (Load Reduced Dual Inline Memory Module) is also registered memory. This is all not to be confused with ECC (Error Correcting) Memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have an ASUS WS C422 SAGE motherboard and tried to install a set of 2 CORSAIR Vengeance RGB PRO 32GB DDR4 3200 (PC4-25600) C16 memory cards into it and am getting an invalid memory configuration error from the motherboard (POST fails).

You purchased incompatible unregistered DDR4 memory.  Specifications for your motherboard specify the following memory configurations are supported.

In order for your motherboard to detect 1024 GB DDR4 specific memory configurations must be used indicated by the manual.

- RDIMM is Registered DIMM while
- LRDIMM is Load Reduced DIMM
- Corsair Vengeance RGB PRO 32GB DDR4 3200 is unregistered DDR4.

> 8 x DIMM, Max. 1024GB, DDR4 2933(O.C.)/2666/2400/2133 MHz RDIMM, LR-DIMM Memory
>
> Does that mean it is different than an "RDIMM" or is "SDRAM" a kind of "RDIMM"?

All you need to know is, your motherboard requires registered DDR4 modules, while you purchased unregistered DDR4 modules.

Comment: Super User isn’t a forum